# Unable to post the required fields into the database

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using MvcApplication4.Models;

namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : ApiController
    {
        private DemoEntities db = new DemoEntities();

        // GET api/Demo
        public IEnumerable<Emp_details> GetEmp_details()
        {
            return db.Emp_details.AsEnumerable();
        }

        // GET api/Demo/5
        public Emp_details GetEmp_details(int id)
        {
            Emp_details emp_details = db.Emp_details.Find(id);
            if (emp_details == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
            }

            return emp_details;
        }

        // PUT api/Demo/5
        public HttpResponseMessage PutEmp_details(int id, Emp_details emp_details)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            if (id != emp_details.Id)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            db.Entry(emp_details).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        // POST api/Demo
        public HttpResponseMessage PostEmp_details(Emp_details emp_details)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Emp_details empobject = new Emp_details();
                //empobject.Id = Convert.ToInt32(val[0]);
                //empobject.name = val[1];
                //empobject.Age = Convert.ToInt32(val[2]);
                db.Emp_details.Add(emp_details);
                db.SaveChanges();



                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, emp_details);
                response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = emp_details }));
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }
        }

        // DELETE api/Demo/5
        public HttpResponseMessage DeleteEmp_details(int id)
        {
            Emp_details emp_details = db.Emp_details.Find(id);
            if (emp_details == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            db.Emp_details.Remove(emp_details);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, emp_details);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to post only particular fields' values into the database not all the values. My database values contain `Id`, `name`, `Age`. I need to post only `Id` and `name` but not `Age`. Is that possible. Please help me out. and Also i need to post the values into different  tables not to the single table.Please help me out fast i need a working code for this

Comment: It is not Java, looks like C#. Why have you tagged Java for it?

Comment: Sorry i forgot its c# only

Comment: Is Age column nullable in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an object like :

```
var post_object = new Emp_details 
{
   id= "Updated ID",
   name = "Updated Name"
};
```

And post this object to your controller.You'll receive this object with `Age` set to it's default value(null if a `Nullable` type) and rest of the fields will have the new data/value(s).

Comment: Yeah i am able to do this thank You.. actually i need to insert the values into multiple tables with the single controller can i do that??

Comment: you have your data, do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Yeah But not knowing how to do it. I can retrieve the values from the different tables and view it on the postman but inserting the values into different tables from the postman was not able to achieve by me.Please help me out

Comment: update your question with your efforts. if inserts were successful, you can peek into the db and make sure.